# Batch file code to reg not working

Tags: batch-file, regedit

**Hi again this has been fixed/answered just I cant answer my own question for 8 hours
... may have stuffed up a line or two with spelling mistakes..
sorry to waste anyone's time and thank you Gary for pointing out to check the reg file.**

Hi everyone this is my first day... yes first day messing around with .bat files, and I have been googling the net for ages to figure this out so any help would be great.

I have been trying to get my .bat file to run a reg file from a different location, the .bat file is on the desktop. the .reg is in a folder which is located on the desktop. 
what I have wrote so far is

```
regedit.exe /s "C:\Users\Crash Bot V1.0\Desktop\Reg Files\ChangeOpenToOpen_With.reg"
```

just to add, this is being done in virtual box on a windows 7 installation.

be as harsh as you feel if it is an idiots mistake, thanks again for any help.

Comment: And what is going wrong?

Comment: I put a `.reg` file on my desktop, and used `regedit.exe /s` to call it from a different folder, and it worked just fine. Perhaps the problem lies within your .reg file? Or the user's permissions?

Comment: ... this was sadly this is awkward, I must of stuffed up my .reg during all my alt-tabbing.... its working now thank you (head hangs in shame)

Comment: Endoro /s makes add the reg file without the prompt being asked so in other words s=silent

Answer (score 0):

was my path and a spelling mistake, found a neat way to avoid this issue if you know where the item is, go to it hold left shift and right click and there is a option called **copy as path** then when you paste you will have the path of your selected item. hope this helps someone.